# How to handle app reinstall and locally stored azure notification hub installationID

Tags: ios, azure, notifications, xamarin.forms

In our Xamarin Forms app we register via a backend with Azure Notification Hub using the installation Model.

When a user creates an account in this multi user app, an installation object is created, the deviceToken (iOS) is set and the installationId is generated as a new Guid and the installation is sent to ANH. Last, the InstallationId is stored on the device locally. All is well.

Now, when reinstalling the app, the InstallationId is no longer in the settings and we can never again update the already existing installation in the hub. Since the iOS deviceToken has not changed, when running the app, we start receiving push notifications from the previous app install. In our app, in theory this could be a totally different user(account).

How would one go about this?

One thing we came up with is calling the backend to unregister all installations by a specific PNS/deviceToken when the app start detects an empty installationId property in the Settings (aka, first app start) but taking a closer look at the azure api, there is no GetInstallationByPushChannel or something that looks like it.

Thanx in advance!